# Windows mobile 10 NetworkAccountId

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, ussd

In order to make a USSD transaction with my windows mobile 10, I use the `UssdSession` class. To create an object, I need either a `NetworkAccountId` or a `NetworkInterfaceId`.

I tried to get the `NetworkAccountId` with:

```
IReadOnlyList<string> networkAccIds = Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.MobileBroadbandAccount.AvailableNetworkAccountIds;
string networkAccountId = networkAccIds[0];
```

But it raised an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

```
Exception levée : 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' dans mscorlib.ni.dll
```

I am running the application on a real a windows handset with a GSM connection. Why am-I not able to get the available network account?

Comment: Based on the documentation you need special permissions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.networking.networkoperators.mobilebroadbandaccount.availablenetworkaccountids

Do you have "privileged access by mobile network operators" ?

Comment: ...and to make this entirely clear for me: the second row throws the exception? So the networkAccIds list is empty, right? ...a check for that is always a good idea!

Comment: Well, the networkAccountId.Count() returns 0. Do you know, how do-I set the "network privilege" for a development purpose?

Comment: Maybe this one can help: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29894  But I don't know more about this...

Comment: It seems that I need to have `cellularDeviceControl`permission. I tried to add it in the manifest without success.